# footer link to a page with hash changed content ready

Tags: routes, javascript, navigation

I have set up the pages like this (using some php and jquery):

On this page, I have some tabs, using jquery to hide and display the content on click each tab. The url will change to #this_tab_name accordingly.

For example, www.mysite.com/thispage#tab1 will be showing the content of tab1 only when someone clicks tab1 on thispage.

Now I want to set up a footer site map, I want some of the menu items link directly to urls like www.mysite.com/thispage#tab1 and also display the right content while hiding the rest. Embedding "thispage#tab1" will only link to thispage, but without the right content.

Any suggestion? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your jquery to document.ready as well as click, that way when a user goes to the page it will load the proper tab for you.

Something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        //bind click event
        jQuery("#tab1").click(show_tab);

        //handle document load
        show_tab();
    }
);

function show_tab()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think this is the problem. everything is in the ready function now. The url just has no impact on the content jquery changes, I still don't know what to do with that.