# call a js function on loading a page

Tags: javascript, 7

is it possible to call a javascript(jquery) function once a particular page is loaded. It should be hacking the  of the whole site and to detect what the current page is and call the function. How can I actually do this?

So in a non-drupal php site, I would add a js file and have a start_product_content() function there. In the head.php file it would be something like this:

```
...
<head>
    ...
    <?php if $current_page = "product" ?>
    start_product_content()
    ...
</head>
...
```

I have explained in a different post about what I really want to achieve, long story: [footer link to a page with hash changed content ready](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85125/footer-link-to-a-page-with-hash-changed-content-ready/85126?noredirect=1#85126)

I have achieved this when I was doing a non-drupal website, now I just want to be able to do this so that I can be closer to the target.

Thanks

Comment: Drupal is a CMS framework that produces HTML/CSS/JS etc. What works in a non-Drupal website will also work in a Drupal website. Presumably you've already tried to implement this, what went wrong? What error messages did you receive? What code did you use to add the JS to the page? Why aren't use using `jQuery.ready()` as was advised in the linked post? All these things needs to be known to help any further. If you're just having a problem with the Javascript syntax I'm afraid this isn't the right place to ask; we deal with Drupal-specific questions only here

Comment: I simply don't know how to add the equivalent php code into a drupal site, so I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start. How can I call a function right in the beginning once detecting the page?

Comment: I'll put an answer in for that specific question, but you're dangerously close to asking "how does Drupal work?" or "How does Drupal's theme system work?", both of which are scarily large topics that we can't cover here. Have you read the docs for theming for example?

Comment: Maybe I am not clear enough, sorry. I am not asking how to add javascript files, I have done that. I am asking, how to call a js function from the file that I have added when the browser has detected the $path_alias is some certain strings that I will specify or, even better, when a particular node type (the pages) is loaded.

Comment: That's not the way to approach it - The conditional should be on the PHP side. Wherever you're adding the JS to the page should contain a conditional of something like `if ($_GET['q'] == 'node/1') { drupal_add_js(...); }` So the javascript simply doesn't get added to pages it shouldn't run for. Then you can just make sure your JS is running when the page is loaded and you're done

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add arbitrary code to the `<head>` element you need to:

1. Take a copy of the core html.tpl.php file and put it in your theme somewhere
2. Clear the caches so it gets added to the theme registry
3. Implement `hook_preprocess_html()` in your theme's template.php file like so

   ```
   function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
     $vars['some_var'] = 'Something';
   }
   ```
4. In the html.tpl.php file, use

   ```
   print $some_var;
   ```

   wherever that might be appropriate.

If you want to add structured code to the `<head>` tag then use [`drupal_add_html_head()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7).

Finally, specifically to add JS to the page, you can use [`drupal_add_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7). But that needs to happen *before* the HTML template is processed. `hook_preprocess_page()` would be one option, but there are many, depending on the context that makes up your page.

You'll find the [Theming guide](https://drupal.org/documentation/theme), and questions already asked on this site, invaluable if you're learning the theme system from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has is own way to add a specific .js file :

Use [drupal_add_js()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

There also a module (with an UI) to add .js file without creating a custom module. Take a look at [JS injector](https://drupal.org/project/js_injector)